# Calculate product of values across dates with multi-index using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am working on a project that requires calculation of linked rate of returns for a dataset that spans across dates. My current data set(df) which is a dataframe that looks like this:

```
  asof_date     index_id       ror
  2015-01-31      x            0.004
  2015-01-31      y            0.03
  2015-01-31      z            0.4
  2015-02-28      x            0.001
  2015-02-28      y            0.02
  2015-02-28      z            0.1
  ....
  2015-06-30      x            0.1
  2015-06-30      y            -0.02
  2015-06-30      z            0.4
```

The current index of df is a multilevel index consists of asof_date and index_id.

I would like to get a linked returned to produce something like this:

```
       index_id       linked_ror
         x             0.5
         y             0.48
         z             0.23
```

where the linked_ror is the product of ror over the dates by index_id.
I have looked at various ways and cannot seem to figure out how this can be done and I will appreciate it if someone can shed some light on this for me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `groupby` on `level='index_id'`, and then aggregrate each group to calculate the product.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# some artificial data
# ==============================
np.random.randn(0)
dates = ['2015-01-31','2015-02-28', '2015-03-31']
idx_id = list('xyz')
multi_index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([dates, idx_id], names=['asof_date', 'index_id'])
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1,5,9), index=multi_index, columns=['ror'])
print(df)

                     ror
asof_date  index_id     
2015-01-31 x           4
           y           2
           z           2
2015-02-28 x           2
           y           1
           z           3
2015-03-31 x           2
           y           1
           z           3

# processing
# ==========================
df.groupby(level='index_id')['ror'].agg(np.prod)

index_id
x    16
y     2
z    18
Name: ror, dtype: int64
```